# Add custom CSS to my Polylang widget and remove bullets - using WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress

I am desperately trying to remove the bullets that appear in front of the flags. I am using WordPress and I've added this Polylang feature as a widget in my header.  I tried to post a screenshot but I can't upload images yet.

I would also like to custom css this widget but I have tried everything I can think of and nothing is happening.  Basically this is placed on the left side of my page when I want it on the right side.  Here is the code I used in the my_functions php:

```
function my_widgets_init() {

) );register_sidebar( array(
'name' => __( 'Header Area', 'your-theme' ),
'id' => 'sidebar-2',
'description' => __( 'An optional widget area for your site header', 'your-theme' ),
'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="headwidget %2$s">',
'after_widget' => "</div>",
'before_title' => '<h3>',
'after_title' => '</h3>',) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'my_widgets_init' );
```

And here is the code used in header.php

```
    <div class="span12" id="polylang-2">
    <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-2') ) : ?> <?php endif; ?></div>
```

I tried entering Custom CSS from the WP admin widgets panel, i have no idea how to code from here I guess cause nothing ever changes... I have already done a lot of customization to my site so I am ok with CSS, it's more finding where to make changes I have trouble with.  And php is not my forte yet.

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can inject a custom class after widget class as shown in the code below:
        'before_widget' => ''

now you can call the class myclass from style.css file present in your theme folder I hope you know how to remove the bullets in the css

you can locate your theme files from wp-content/themes/themename

```
.myclass {float:left;} /* to move it on the left */
.myclass ul {list-style:none;}
```

Moreover you dont require a div with the id polylang-2 since the div automatically comes from the above widget code.

and you can change the header.php code to

```
<?php dynamic_sidebar("sidebar-2");?>
```

OR

the next way around is if you want to use your existing code then add the following css in your style.css file inside your theme

```
#polylang-2 ul {list-style:none;}
```

Let me know if it solves your problem or not. Thanks

Comment: OK so I went with the first suggestion, changed the php code in the header.php, added the css to my stylesheet, and yes I am good with the CSS, now the only thing I don't understand is where and how I inject a custom class, in here somewhere?  'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="headwidget %2$s">',